# how can we call a http servlet from mule?

Tags: servlets, mule

I have a requirement in which i need to call a servlet from mule flow.I got one answer from the below site

http://mule.1045714.n5.nabble.com/Creating-query-string-for-calling-a-servlet-td2665836.html

But when i copy that code in my flow it is showing some errors in flow. Is there any other method or solution to call servlet from mule. I have servlet URL and username and password. I am using mule 3.5 anypoint studio. Please help me in completing this task

EDIT: (Pasted from a comment from the OP)

```
<flow name="CallServletServiceFlow1" doc:name="CallServletServiceFlow1">
  <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP" address="localhost:8080/servlet"/>
  <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
  <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" user="javauser" password="javauser1" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" address="servlet/customTaskServlet?" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be copying old Mule 2 syntax in Mule 3, so this can not work.

Just use a simple HTTP outbound endpoint in your flow.

Reference: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference

EDIT: If you use the `address` attribute in HTTP endpoints (instead of the `host` `port` and `path`), you need to specify the scheme. So for example, you should replace `address="localhost:8080/servlet"` with `address="http://localhost:8080/servlet"`.

Comment: Hi david        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" user="javauser" password="javauser1" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" address="" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS"/>

Comment: I am using hte above outbound endpoint for calling servlet.when i hit the url from browser i m able to get the servlet,when i try to hit from mule i m unable to get the same

Comment: The `address` attribute is empty: you need to put the HTTP URI in it.

Comment: yes i added IT AND TRIED.As it is confidential in the post i kept it as empty. <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" user="javauser" password="javauser1" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" address="http://ServletAddress" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS"/>.This is a get method username and password generally we used to pass in url itself.In mule i m passing it as above shown

Comment: Mmmh, OK. So what error do you get? Pastebin it and link it here.

Comment: my flow is <flow name="CallServletServiceFlow1" doc:name="CallServletServiceFlow1"> <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP" address="http://localhost:8080/servlet"/> <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/> <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" user="javauser" password="javauser1" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" address="http://servlet/customTaskServlet?" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS"/> </flow>

Comment: The error i am getting when i hit from browser is Error 404 - page not found Sorry, we can't find what you are looking for. Return

Comment: Not sure why you added your flow in a comment instead of in your question. Anyway, I've fixed your question for you and edited my answer accordingly.